# How do you get third link from BeautifulSoup result

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am using the following code to retrieve a bunch of links using BeautifulSoup. It returns all the links, but I would like to get the third link, parse through that one, and then get the third from that one and so on. How can I modify the below code to accomplish that?

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *

url = raw_input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print tag.get('href', None)
    print tag.contents[0]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should stop using `BeautifulSoup` version 3 - it is quite old and no longer maintained. Switch to [`BeautifulSoup` version 4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Install it via:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

And change your import to:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Then, you need to use `find_all()` and get the 3rd link by index recursively until there is no 3rd link on a page. Here is one way to do it:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = raw_input('Enter - ')

while True:
    html = urllib.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

    try:
        url = soup.find_all('a')[2]["href"]
        # if the link is not absolute, you might need `urljoin()` here
    except IndexError:
        break  # could not get the 3rd link - exiting the loop
```

Comment: Thank you for responding alecxe. In the above code, "tags = soup('a') returns a list. Then when executing "print" I get  many links. So it appears to be giving me all the links without using "find_all". What I am confused by is why I cant' simply print tags[2] which I would assume to be the 3 rd link that the loop iterates to.

Comment: @martinbshp yes, the `soup()` is a shortcut to `soup.find_all()`. Yes, you need to get the `href` attribute value as demonstrated in the answer.

Comment: Oh! I got it now. Your response prompted me to go back and re-think this thing and see how tags is whose index I need to interrogate not the tag var in the for loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a [*css selector*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors),[*nth-of-type*](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) to get the third anchor looping until the css select returns None:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = raw_input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
a = soup.select_one("a:nth-of-type(3)")
while a:
    html = urllib.urlopen(a["href"])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    a = soup.select_one("a:nth-of-type(3)")
```

If you wanted to find the third anchor that had a href attribute, you could use `"a:nth-of-type(3)[href]"`